# The tour logo is different to the favicon icon / Логотип на странице Тур отличается от favicon сайта

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

In the tour, the logo has 3 different colours. However in the tab the favicon / icon has just blue.

Tour / Тур

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Icon / значок

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Is this a mistake, or are the smaller icons meant to be different?

---

На странице [**Тур**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) нижняя часть логотипа раскрашена в русский триколор.
В favicon сайта нижняя часть иконки раскрашена в монотонный синий.
Так и задумано, что favicon должен отличаться от крупной иконки, или это ошибка?

Comment: +1 just was going to report it!!

Comment: @nicael I'm just browsing around for problems - doing what I do best :P everyone will learn to hate my vaguely translated russian!

Comment: Can't judge however :D but from my experience, Google doesn't have a high-quality translation of sentences; check vice versa just in case. Also, the better way is just add more images with colourful freehand and you'll have a chance to be understood :) (this question is perfectly illustratable I believe, have a try)

Comment: Also: [per-site (not in the network profile) account list](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pDNFZ.png) & ["main / meta user" links](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pnlZg.png) & [Community Bulletin](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hOkYG.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Иконку несколько раз меняли туда-сюда, судя по всему. Иконка в туре (она же иконка apple), иконка для сайта, иконка для чата находятся в рассинхронизированном состоянии. Похоже, никак не могут определиться, как раскрасить иконку.

Я создал тему на Meta.StackExchange.com: [**Иконки для локализованных сайтов Stack Overflow сбивают с толку**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252622/less-confusing-icons-for-localized-stack-overflows). Как мне видится, проблема не только в окончательном выборе, но и в содержательности, узнаваемости иконки. Я предложил использовать код языка, а не выбранные от балды цвета с флагов стран, где проживает основное население, говорящее на языке сайта.

Прежде чем "исправлять" иконку, для начала надо убедиться, что это именно та иконка, которая всех удовлетворит.

---

Icons seem to be changing back and forth. Tour icon (aka apple icon), fav icon, chat icon are not synchronized. Looks like site owners can't decide what icon to choose.

I've created a topic on Meta.StackExchange.com: [**Less confusing icons for localized Stack Overflows**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252622/less-confusing-icons-for-localized-stack-overflows). The way I see it, the problem is not only in deciding what icon to use once and for all, but in the icon being informative and easy to recognize. Choosing random colors from the flags of the countries where majority of the language speakers live is hardly the best option. Language codes would be much better.

Before "fixing" the icon, we need to make sure it's the icon we want.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252699/imgur-com-is-getting-an-old-new-verson-of-an-image-from-the-se-servers, it now seems to be fixed at the blue bar, and the tour has updated.